# Creating popout window with buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a small game that showes you a window with 8 buttons and you select one to win. Next 7 buttons should be a miss. The window is poping out, but theres no buttons. Any ideas what's wrong with the code?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

t = Tk()
t.title("Select button")
t.geometry("300x350")

def insert_buttons():
     count_buttons=8
     global buttons
     buttons = []
     good = random.randint (0,count_buttons-1)
     for i in range (count_buttons):
          if  i == good:
               buttons.append(Button(t, text  = "Select", command=hit))
          else:
               buttons.append(Button(t, text = "Select", command=miss))
     for i in buttons:
          i.pack (fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

def hit():
     for i in buttons:
          i.destroy()
     global etykiet
     etykiet = label(t, text = "BRAWO! It's a hit!")
     etykiet.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
     t.after(5000,restart)

def miss():
     for i in buttons:
          i.destroy()
          global etykiet
          etykieta = label(t, text - "Try again")
          etykieta.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
          t.after(5000, restart)

def restart():
     etyket.destroy()
     inserty_buttons()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code up and it should be working. There were quite a few errors, remember to go through your code and check the documentations. Also i recommend using 4 spaces indentation

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

t = Tk()
t.title("Select button")
t.geometry("300x350")


def insert_buttons():
     count_buttons = 8
     global buttons
     buttons = []
     good = random.randint(0, count_buttons - 1)
     for i in range(count_buttons):
          if i == good:
               buttons.append(Button(t, text="Select", command=hit))
          else:
               buttons.append(Button(t, text="Select", command=miss))
     for i in buttons:
          i.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)


def hit():
    currentbuttons = globals()['buttons']
    globals()['buttons'] = []
    for i in currentbuttons:
          i.destroy()
          etykieta = Label(t, text="BRAVO! ITS A HIT")
          etykieta.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
          buttons.append(etykieta)
    t.after(2000, restart)


def miss():
    currentbuttons = globals()['buttons']
    globals()['buttons'] = []
    for i in currentbuttons:
          i.destroy()
          etykieta = Label(t, text="Try again")
          etykieta.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
          buttons.append(etykieta)
    t.after(2000, restart)


def restart():
     for button in globals()['buttons']:
        button.destroy()
     globals()['buttons'] = []
     insert_buttons()


insert_buttons()
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your going to get 'Try again' in 8 labels using this

Comment: it was like that originaly @Barb, I just made it work